# Apache using 100% CPU, once again

Tags: cpu, apache-http-server

Recently, apache2 started using 100% of CPU power:
`top` gives me [image: 100% cpu usage]

From other, similar threads, I took the tip to use mod_status. Aside from HUGE amounts of NULL requests, it gives:

```
CPU Usage: u2.16 s1.32 cu0 cs0 - .0835% CPU load
1.2 requests/sec - 17.6 kB/second - 14.6 kB/request
8 requests currently being processed, 42 idle workers
```

The access and error logs do not show anything surprising or intriguing at all.

Note the .8% CPU usage. Another tip was to use `strace`:

```
root@server:~# strace -p 1956
Process 1956 attached - interrupt to quit
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted call ...>
```

And remains like this for at least half an hour, without producing any additional output.
Restarting apache fixed the problem for less than a second
The server runs a few custom python scripts aswell as a django-powered website on apache2 (up-to-date), but even turning the scripts off (or not having them active in the first place) did not change anything.
After I stopped apache and powered my server off, powered it on a few minutes afterwards and restarted all my services, the CPU usage remained low for several hours, just in order to pop up again randomly (?)

The DigitalOcean CPU stats on my server are:
[image: DigitalOcean stats]
You can see how the CPU usage was super high for almost half a day until I restarted the bot - just to remain stable for several hours and then pop up again.

I am completely at a loss of words and don't know what I could do to find out what piece of my code is giving me these problems or if apache itself is the cause...

Therefore I would greatly appreciate any hints to the questions: What else can I try to do? Which things might I not have checked? Is this definitely in my own code? How do you find what part of python code crashes an app via a infinite loop or similar?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what operating system and Apache version are you using.

Comment: Sorry about that, its Debian 7 x86, apache2 -v gives: Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

Comment: So you're getting high CPU usage even if you're serving an empty website? You said that you turned the scripts off, but you didn't say what you did with the Django application. Also check out this [Linux performance](http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html) material.

Comment: The django app was obviously still running. I suspect its some part of my code (perhaps some caching routine) that gets caught in a infinite loop. What I dont understand is why mod_status reports <1% CPU usage

Comment: How is the Django application integrated with the Apache server? Does it depend on any external resources like a database?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu yes, it relies upon 2 sqlite3 databases, aside from the db.sqlite3 that django uses - If that were the bottleneck, wouldnt I be expecting to see alot of disk usage or system calls then?

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily see a lot of disk usage. System calls maybe. By the way, what do [**vmstat**](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=vmstat&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy) or [**sar**](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sar&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy) say? You also haven't answered how it's integrated with Apache, if you're using **mod\_python**, **mod\_wsgi** etc.

Comment: I didnt install any additional modules, so I guess I use mod_wsgi, since django uses that by default.
I will try vmstat and sar once the problem occurs again (it has not been happening for several hours now)